# angular2 It appears only as an object object on the screen

Tags: angular, angular2-services

On the view screen, you can not get the desired json key value.
I tried the following. board.component.html

**board.component.html**

{{board.title}} > [Object Object],

{{board?.title}} > Nothing ,

{{board | Json}} > [{ "title" : "AAAAAA", "cont" : "AAAA1234", "date" : "2017-03-03", "hit" : "5" }]

**board.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector : 'board',
    templateUrl : './board.component.html'
})

export class boardComponent implements OnInit{
    pageTitle : string = 'board';
    errorMessage : string;
    board : Board[];

    constructor(private _boardService : BoardService){}

    ngOnInit() : void {
        this._boardService.getBoard()
            .subscribe(
                boards => this.board = boards, 
                error => this.errorMessage = <any> error
            );
        console.log('board In OnInit');
    }
}
```

**board.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class BoardService{
    private _boardUrl = '/src/api/board/board.json';

    constructor(private _http : Http){}

    getBoard() : Observable<Board[]>{
        return this._http.get(this._boardUrl)
            .map((response : Response) => <Board[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('Board : ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error : Response){
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide board.component.html, may be relevant part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  *ngFor since board  is an array. Or if you want to access the first element you can do this,

```
{{board[0]?.title}}
```

Comment: wondering how can you suggest this?,  he has't provided board.component.html code yet. and {{board?.title}} could be part of for loop..

Comment: @Dipak check the first line